# What is intended and the difference between "localMemberHost" and "localMemberBindAddress"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

"The bind address of this member. The difference between localMemberHost & localMemberBindAddress
  is that localMemberHost is the one that is advertised by this member, while localMemberBindAddress
  is the address to which this member is bound to."

We are in the process of making API Manager components HA ready. As a result of that, we are upgrading configurations as per the cluster guide. HazelcastClusteringAgent configs are getting updated as well. As I quoted at the top most section provided comment is bit unclear, much appreciated if you can eloborate more. Furthermore, would like to know that, this is still a valid set of parameters that need to be fulfilled if we are following the AWS clustering configs for Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

In the event of AWS clustering the bind address is constructed (if using aws discovery) by the resulting IP address returned from the ec2:describe instances and the configured listen port (5701 default). So you would not set the bind address it is set by the plugin.